# Need help with regular expression

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I am using Django for my application and needed to do a pattern matching

Pattern to be matched: users/?q=john
Regular expression :  '^users/\?q\=(?P[\w]+)[/]?$'

like this in urls.py

url(r'^users/\?q\=(?P[\w]+)[/]?$', user_handler, {'emitter_format' : 'json'})

However it's not matching the URL, any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CGI, everything after ? is put into request.GET and does not even get to url matching - take a look here:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/

In your handler (`user_handler`), you can use:

```
request.GET['q']
```

to get `john` from the above sample URL.

Comment: thanks it worked as you suggested, I changed the URL Pattern to just ^users/ and it worked like a charm